# Send data to external webview

Tags: javascript, webview, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to send some data from app.js to an open webview (external url, example: http://mysite.com/file.html), without success. I've check through many questions and answers and tried different solutions with Ti.App.fireEvent and Ti.App.addEventListener without any good success. I did however find a solution that did this with a local html-file some time ago, but weren't able to recreate this for an external.

app.js

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('helloWorld', { data : "Hello World" );
```

http://mysite.com/file.html

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('helloWorld', function(e) 
{   
    // do something with e.data
});
```

doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: dont really understand the question, can you be more specific?

Comment: updated the question, might be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by using evalJS
app.js

```
web.addEventListener('load', function() {

        var data = "some data";
        web.evalJS("testJS('" + data + "')");

});
```

http://mysite.com/file.html

```
<script>
    function testJS (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Extremely hacky, but that's what you have to do with Appcelerator, I guess :/

I'm probably going to try to widget-ize this so it's easy. Just reference the widget and give it the data. Streamline the JS function to do the same thing for each individual widget that needs this, you know?

Thanks for the tip, Miyao

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, this only works in the iPhone simulator but not in the Android simulator (1.6 API and 2.2 API).  In Android, you get the dreaded "Force Close" button.